# A hybrid way to produce high resolution ggplot image using RStudio's export function?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggplot2 with RStudio to produce a 300 dpi image. However the method using "tiff("test.tif"...)" produced a wired image with very big text and very small plot; while the export function in RStudio  is convenient to use with helpful interactive graphics to scale but falls short in producing a low resolution 72 dpi image.
Is there any hybrid way with the both high resolution and interactive image operations?

Comment: Unfortunately, what you see on your screen in RStudio is by definition a low DPI figure. And you'll find that saving that image either as a high pixel count image or large-dimension PDF out of the interactive window will yield some less than desirable results. In general I've found it's always best to call the graphics device of your choice explicitly and tailor your output's size, resolution, and formatting options by hand. But there may be better ways.

Comment: `ggsave` uses the dimensions of your interactive graphics by default and has a convenient `scale` argument.

Comment: Thank you, shadow. ggsave is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Answered in comments:

#### 1. Create a plot

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point()
```

#### 2. Save it via `ggsave()`

```
> ggsave("mtcars.pdf")
Saving 4.11 x 4.08 in image
```

#### 3. Play with the `scale =` argument

```
> ggsave("mtcars.pdf", scale = 2)
Saving 8.23 x 8.17 in image
```

The proportions should stay the same.